# Get row as object where checkbox is checked in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, frontend

i'm using datatable library and trying to get the entire row as object where checkbox "editado" is checked
[image]
I'm using the folowing code:

> var a = $('#ContratoAlertaTabela').DataTable().rows(function (idx,
> data, node) {
> return $(node).find('.editado:input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked');
> }).data().toArray();

But it gives as object like:

```
0:
dataAssinatura: "2022-05-20T00:00:00"
dataTermino: "2022-05-13T00:00:00"
descricao: "Descrição 2021"
diasRestantes: -18
exercicio: 2021
fornecedor: "fornecedor 2"
id: 6
numero: "23452345"
tipo: "C"
visto: true
```

But i'm looking for this

```
0:
dataAssinatura: "2022-05-20T00:00:00"
dataTermino: "2022-05-13T00:00:00"
descricao: "Descrição 2021"
diasRestantes: -18
exercicio: 2021
fornecedor: "fornecedor 2"
id: 6
numero: "23452345"
tipo: "C"
visto: true
editado: true
```

[image]

And this is my datatable

```
var l = abp.localization.getResource('Contabilidade');
    var dataTable = $('#ContratoAlertaTabela').DataTable(
        abp.libs.datatables.normalizeConfiguration({
            serverSide: true,
            paging: true,
            'order': [[2, 'asc']],
            //order: false, //[[0, "asc"]],
            searching: true,
            scrollX: true,
            ajax: abp.libs.datatables.createAjax(gcaspp.contabilidade.contratoAlerta.contratoAlerta.getListAlerta,
                () => {
                    var visto = $("#ExibirVisto").is(":checked") ? "" : "true";
                    return { visto: visto };
                }),
            dom: '<"toolbar">',
            columnDefs: [ 
                {
                    title: 'Visto',
                    data: "visto",
                    orderable: false,
                    render: function (data) {
                        if (data) {
                            return '<input type="checkbox" name="cbox1" value="" checked>';
                        } else {
                            return '<input type="checkbox" name="cbox1" value="" >';
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    title: 'Editado',
                    render: function (data) {
                        return '<input type="checkbox" class="editado" name="teste" value="" >';
                    }
                },
                {
                    title: "visto",
                    data: "visto"
                },
                {
                    title: "id",
                    data: "id"
                },
                {
                    title: 'Tipo',
                    data: "tipo"
                },
                {
                    title: 'Numero',
                    data: "numero"
                },
                {
                    title: 'Exercicio',
                    data: "exercicio"
                },
                {
                    title: 'Descricao',
                    data: "descricao"
                },
                {
                    title: 'Fornecedor',
                    data: "fornecedor"
                },
                {
                    title: 'DataAssinatura',
                    data: "dataAssinatura"
                },
                {
                    title: 'DataTermino',
                    data: "dataTermino"
                },
                {
                    title: 'DiasRestantes',
                    data: "diasRestantes"
                }
            ]
        })
    );
```

Any ideia about what i can do?

Comment: It looks like *editado* is not part of the original data set. You are querying the row data with `.data()` **NOT** what is in the HTML

Comment: Since you're getting the data ONLY for the 'CHECKED' editado, even if you had it, it would be always true. So, you can add this property in your returned data as true. Also looks like you're trying to edit complete row using the checkbox, I'd suggest checking this solution https://github.com/sinhashubh/datatable-examples . With this you'll be able to edit complete row's without opening a modal popup.